# Codeigniter resize image not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 2.1.2 on Win 8.1

and the following code is not working

```
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
    $config['source_image'] = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/imgt/wall/wallpaper2.jpg';

    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']     = 75;
    $config['height']   = 50;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

    var_dump( $this->image_lib->resize()); // this returns true
```

What is the problem i checked GD is installed  ??

I also tried the same code in 2.2.0 here too not working

Comment: any errors you are getting

Comment: check the folder has a write permission to store the resize image

Comment: use `echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();` in your code and tell what error its thrown

Comment: Tamil Selvan no errors

Comment: @TamilSelvan var_dump returning empty string so there is no errors i also checked GD library it is enabled. then what is the problem ??

Comment: @TamilSelvan I which directory i should expect output 'C:/xampp/htdocs/imgt/wall/' or any other

Comment: remove this line `$this->load->library('image_lib');`

Comment: @TamilSelvan still not working